# Android DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString which supports Timezone

Tags: android

Currently, I'm looking for function, which able to provide humanize date.

`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString` is closed but not exactly what I want.

This is because I need to deal with date/ time of multiple countries.

For instance,

```
timestamp X may represent 6am in Country A, and 11pm in Country B
timestamp Y may represent 8am in Country A, and  2am in Country B
```

So, If I use timestamp Y as **now** and timestamp X as **time**,

```
For timezone in Country A, it should yield "today".
For timezone in Country B, it should yield "yesterday".
```

`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString` however doesn't accept timezone. Is there any equivalent lib, or function which able to do the similar thing, by accepting timezone?